# Rendering material-ui-next Checkbox inside a Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I am having some trouble trying to render a simple `material-ui-next` checkbox inside a `redux-form`. I am following the [official example](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/material-ui/) and trying to adapt it to the `material-ui-next` equivalent, since the example is using the older version of `material-ui`. This is the code that I end up using:

```
const renderCheckbox = ({ input, label }) => (
  <FormGroup row>
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          checked={input.value ? true : false}
          onChange={input.onChange}
          value="checkedA"
        />
      }
      label="Secondary"
    />
  </FormGroup>
);
```

And this is how I define the checkbox inside `redux-form`:

```
...
<Field name="activated" component={renderCheckbox} label="Activated" />
...
```

However when I save the code, React is complaining with the following error:

> index.js:2178 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at myForm.js:108.

Line 108 of the code is the `<Checkbox />` component that is defined inside the aforementioned `renderCheckbox()` method.

Comment: Are you importing things correctly into your component file? I ran your above code without problem. It looks like you may be incorrectly importing the `Checkbox` component based on the error line number.

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck on this issue for quite some time when I finally found a fix to this.
It never works for a functional component which returns a check box. 
I made a separate class component and wrapped it in  Redux Field component and it worked perfectly. I really never understood why it didn't work for the fucntional component as it what is shown in their official example.

I have written the code that worked for me. Hope it helps :)

```
class CheckBoxInput extends React.Component {

  onCheckBoxSelectChange = (input) => 
  {
    input.onChange();
    this.props.onSelectChange();
  }

  render() {
    const { label, input,} = this.props;
    let name = input.name;

    return (
      <div>
        <InputLabel htmlFor={label} style={{paddingTop: '15px'}}> {label} </InputLabel>
         <FormControl {...input} >
          <Checkbox
            name = {name}
            label = {label}
            color= "primary"
            checked={input.value ? true : false}
            onChange={() => this.onCheckBoxSelectChange(input)}
          />          
        </FormControl>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

const CheckBox = (props) => <Field component={CheckBoxInput} {...props} />;
export default CheckBox;
```

And to use this checkbox component:

```
 <CheckBox  name="isCurrent" label="Current" onSelectChange = {this.toggleCurrentEmployerSelection} />
```