# Redux form material-ui checkbox not functioning

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I have a form set up with redux-form to supply the initial values (although it also handles the values so that they're changed in the redux store too) as so below.

But my checkboxes are unable to be interacted with.  They always stay checked (which is their initial value based off the model supplied)

My render method: (I copied the renderCheckbox from [this documentation](https://redux-form.com/6.6.2/examples/material-ui/).

```
render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;

    const renderTextField = ({input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom}) => (
        <TextField
            error={touched && error}
            {...input}
            {...custom}
        />
    );

    const renderCheckbox = ({ input, label }) => (
        <Checkbox
            label={label}
            checked={input.value ? true : false}
            //onCheck={input.onChange} // I had this enabled but it didn't do anything
        />
    );
    const { submit, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.sendSubmit)}>
            <Paper className={classes.sectionPaper}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography className={classes.sectionHeader}>Artifact Info</Typography>
                    <Divider />
                </CardContent>
                <CardContent>
                    <Grid fluid>
                        <Row>
                            <Col xs={12} lg={4}>
                                <CardContent className={classes.artifactCardContent}>
                                    <Typography>Artifact Name</Typography>
                                    <Divider />
                                    <Field
                                        fullWidth
                                        name="Name"
                                        component={renderTextField}
                                        label="Artifact Name"
                                    />
                                </CardContent>
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={6} lg={1}>
                                <CardContent className={classes.artifactCardContent}>
                                    <Typography>Mythic?</Typography>
                                    <Divider />
                                    <Field
                                        name="Mythic"
                                        component={renderCheckbox}
                                        label="Mythic"
                                    />
                                </CardContent>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>
                </CardContent>
            </Paper>



        </form>
);
```

Edit:  Figured it out.  The issue was between material-ui@next and material-ui v1.0 they changed checkboxes to use `checked` for always being checked (based on an initial value), and `defaultChecked` to be a default value.

Comment: it would be nice if you provide your code in sandbox

Comment: There's too many dependencies to run this one page that it'd just be easier for you to clone the repo and run it yourself (if you have docker.  Instructions for running are in readme.)  https://bitbucket.org/cclloyd9785/opensrd-fullstack/src/master/

Comment: I have answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49861654/rendering-material-ui-next-checkbox-inside-a-redux-form).
Please follow this link.